# Is it better to compile bitcoin node or rather for some reason just use the official binaries?

Tags: security, full-node, compiling

As I have some doubts about a possible hackers' attacks on https://bitcoin.org/

Wanting to [run a full node](https://bitcoin.org/en/full-node), I rather compiled the [Bitcoin Core](https://bitcoin.org/en/bitcoin-core/) from [git source](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/build-unix.md) for Linux instead.

The question is:

Does compiling it bring, other than the one - mentioned, benefit to me or to the network?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you can compile your node, do it. well done! for most of the users it is technically nearly impossible to compile a bitcoin node because most of people have not enough technical knowledge. bitcoin.org provides binaries so that all people (who have not the time and knowledge to compile it) can also run a node.

hint: if you want to be 100% sure that you have a legit node, you must compile the libraries which a bitcoin node uses too, because the websites/binaries of every library which will be used by a bitcoin node can also be hacked theoretically.